# 500 Error: Closing tag without opener: /content hogan.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache, hogan.js

Using this code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/1854699 .

I have written this code

Base.html: https://gist.github.com/3438843

index.html: https://gist.github.com/3438868

But I get a 500 error, I have clearly opened the content tag.

Comment: from Base.html: <div role="main">{{$content}}{{/contentb}}</div> didnt you mean "/content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hogan appears to have trouble with inheritance at the moment.